# When posting through facebook API as user to a page, only the poster user can see the post

Tags: facebook, api, post

I want everybody to see posts made through API calls as users even not logged in users.

I am using api explorer to test the following.

I want certain users of my site to be able to post to various facebook pages (who's url or id they choose) using my facebook application.

For this, I have 2 different test users on facebook: one that owns the facebook application and one that owns the page to post to and I am using 2 different browsers to test.

1. I log in with the fb app owner
2. I go to api explorer, select the fb application to use in the dropdown box at the top and get an access token with publish_actions and publish_stream permissions
3. I submit a post to /pageusername/feed with only a message parameter which works and returns a post id (postid)
4. If I click the post id in api explorer after receiving it (~do a GET on /postid) I receive this error: 
   "error": {
   "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
   "type": "GraphMethodException", 
   "code": 100
   }
5. If I go to the facebook page url (while being logged as the one that made the post - the app owner not the page owner) I can see my post on the page in the "posts by others" section
6. If I use the other browser (logged in as a different user - page owner) to go to the page I do not see the post of the other user on the page.
7. I mention that if I post manually using the 2 accounts both users can see the other's posts, only if posted through API calls and api explorer can't see.

Why is this happening?

All privacy settings are set to public for that page and application sandbox mode is turned off. Is there something else I have to do to achieve this ?

I have not submitted the application to the application center, could this be the cause?

I have also tried using JS api calls from a page on my server with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I think this was happening because of the "visibility of posts made by the application" setting in the user account settings was "Only me". I had to go to my account settings then Apps and edit the Visibility of app and posts to "Public". I hope this will help others.